What coordinate substitution should I perform to evaluate this triple integral?
I am trying to evaluate the following triple integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{4-4x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-4x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{4x^2 + z^2}}^2 ye^{4x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \, dy\, dz\, dx
\end{equation}
My work so far is as follows. Firstly, I noticed that trying to integrate $e^{4x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ directly with respect to $x$, $y$, or $z$ is probably futile. As a result, I've been trying to change the coordinate system from Cartesian to another coordinate system (probably cylindrical or spherical).
For reference, the region of integration is a cone with height along the $y$-axis:

As a result, I was motivated to use cylindrical coordinates. However, I've had difficulties with this, due to the $\sqrt{4x^2 + z^2}$ in the limits of integration not seeming to correspond well to cylindrical coordinates, and also the same issue for the $4x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ exponent in the function.
My only other idea was to use spherical coordinates, motivated by the presence of $4x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ (since $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \rho$ in spherical coordinates). However, describing the region of integration using spherical coordinates is difficult.
Can anyone provide hints/a solution to this problem? I've tried everything I know, but I'm still stuck.

The factor of $y$ in the integrand makes the $y$ integration easy, you might perform that integral and take a look at what you get.

@WW1 Good point. Then, I get the integral $\int_{-1}{1} \int_{-\sqrt{4-4x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-4x^2}} \frac{1}{2}(e^4 - e^{4x^2 + z^2})$. Now, the $e^{4x^2 + z^2}$ makes me think to use a polar coordinate substitution, but it's not $x^2 + z^2$, it's $4x^2 + z^2$.

Substituting $x\to\dfrac x2$ would take care of that.

The point is to come up with your own coordinate systems based on the tools you have in your toolbox. For example, there is nothing special about $z$ in cylindrical coordinates, you can just as easily center the system on any of the other two axes (which one should you do here?) Similarly, you don't need to choose "equal magnitude" trig functions for the polar coordinates since there is no reason for the level sets to be circular. You can choose one of sine or cosine to have a factor of $2$. Write out the whole variable transformation with your decision (of the form $x=\cdots$, $y=\cdots$, etc

You are trying to calculate the integral over the region enclosed by the cone $y^2 = 4x^2 + z^2$ and the plane $y = 2$ as is show in the image:

Notice that if we view the cone in the $xz$ plane at $y = y_0$ we get an elipse
$$
1 = \frac{4x^2}{(y_0)^2} + \frac{z^2}{(y_0)^2}
$$

Such elipse can be parametrized by
$$
\sigma_{y_0}(r, \theta) := \left(\frac{y_0r}{2}\cos(\theta), y_0, y_0 r\sin(\theta)\right)
$$
for $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. Thus, the whole region can be parametrized by
$$
\tau(r, \theta, y) := \left(\frac{yr}{2}\cos(\theta), y, yr\sin(\theta)\right)
$$
for $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq y \leq 2$.
In other words, you can use the substitution
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{yr}{2}\cos(\theta),\\
y &= y,\\
z &= yr\sin(\theta).
\end{align*}
with integration limits $0 \leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq y \leq 2$. If you do so, the resulting integral should be easier. When calculating the integral don´t forget to calculate the jacobian of the change of coordinates.
